# Automatically creating tables in an SSIS package with EzAPI

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ezapi

I wouldn't be suprised if this turned out to be a BIDS function rather than available through EzAPI.

I've written some code using EzAPI to generate an SSIS package with an OLEDB source and destination. The Destination table however does not exist and I'd like it to be created in the same way the new button would work in BIDS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general you are right, that this is a functionality of the BIDS. But you can use  SQL Task Component for running DDL Script.

The Destination component has also  ValidateExternalMetadata property. If you set it to false, then SSIS will not validate you the destination against the database. This flag can be used if the destination table does not exist when you are generating your package . In your case you should disable validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create tables (or run other DDL) from an SSIS Control Flow. Is there some reason that approach won't work for you here?

Comment: The SSIS packages are generated dynamically from the underlying access databases and so this would mean creating the DDL programatically (converting types and so on). In fact this is what I'm doing now as the project had to move on.